# Custom button appearing on all product pages in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently using this code with a hook to a specific product but the button seems to be appearing for all other products on my website as well.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','additional_single_product_button');
function additional_single_product_button() {
$product_ids = is_single(871);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo '<div>';
    echo '<a data-type="inline"  class="button alt" href="/contact-us/">Pay at Spa @ $218 nett</a>';
echo '</div>';}
```

Here's my website: http://offers.elements.com.sg/

Please advise how I can just add this button for a specific product. Thank you.

Comment: View: [WooCommerce: is_single() Doesn’t Work](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-is_singlexxx-doesnt-work-resolved/)

Comment: There is no if statement in your code